# Why my feature map seems incorrect when the prediction of the class is correct

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, feature-extraction

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor

# Data processing
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
        std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    )])

image_path = './data/test_images/anemone.jpg'
image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
img_processed = preprocess(image)
batch_img_cat_tensor = torch.unsqueeze(img_processed, 0)

# Model initialization
resnet50_model = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
# Eval model for predictions
resnet50_model.eval()

# Creating feature extractor (Detailed example here: https://pytorch.org/blog/FX-feature-extraction-torchvision/)
feature_extractor = create_feature_extractor(resnet50_model, 
                                             return_nodes=['layer4.2.conv3', 'fc'])

# Forward pass
out = feature_extractor(batch_img_cat_tensor)
pred = torch.argmax(out['fc'])

# Transforming last conv output to numpy and reshaping it so that the channels would be last
last_conv_output = torch.squeeze(out['layer4.2.conv3'])
last_conv_output = torch.reshape(last_conv_output, (7, 7, -1))
last_conv_output = last_conv_output.detach().numpy()
last_conv_output = last_conv_output.astype(np.uint8)

Calculating the upscale factors for last conv output
width_factor = int(image.size[0] / last_conv_output.shape[0])
height_factor = int(image.size[1] / last_conv_output.shape[1])


# Getting the shapes of the last conv output
last_conv_w, last_conv_h, n_channels = last_conv_output.shape
# Calculate the 
upscaled_h = last_conv_h * height_factor
upscaled_w = last_conv_w * width_factor

# Upscaling the last_conv_output so that it could be "masked" with original image
upsampled_last_conv_output = np.zeros((upscaled_h, upscaled_w, n_channels))
upsampled_last_conv_output = []

for x in range(0, n_channels, 512):
    upsampled_last_conv_output.append(cv2.resize(last_conv_output[:, :, x:x+512], (upscaled_w, upscaled_h), cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
    
upsampled_last_conv_output = np.concatenate(upsampled_last_conv_output, axis=2)

# Getting the weights of the predicted class
last_layer_weights = resnet50_model.fc.weight.T
last_layer_weights_for_pred = last_layer_weights[:, pred]

# Dot multiplying the upsampled_last_conv_output with last_layer_weights_for_pred
upsampled_last_conv_output = upsampled_last_conv_output.reshape((-1, 2048))
heat_map = np.dot(upsampled_last_conv_output,
                  last_layer_weights_for_pred.detach().numpy()).reshape(upscaled_h, upscaled_w)

# Plotting the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image)
ax.imshow(heat_map, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_title(prediction)
```

I have followed the tutorial from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiyldmoYe_M&t=665s&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni

The main problem with this is that I get the feature map that looks like this:

[image: Incorrect feature map]

As you see it looks like the model reacts to multiple areas on the image and no matter what image I use  it always has the biggest reaction in the middle.

PS. If you think this question should be posted on the AI stack exchange please notify me

Answer (score 0):

I have found an error I made. It was that after creating a

```
heat_map = np.dot(upsampled_last_conv_output, last_layer_weights_for_pred.detach().numpy()).reshape(upscaled_h, upscaled_w)
```

I had to apply this as well:

```
heat_map = heat_map - np.min(heat_map)
heat_map = heat_map / np.max(heat_map)
```

Since I normalized the image, the generated heatmap was also normalized, so I needed to "denormalize" it back to it's original values.